# How to write schema for relational database (MySQL) to join more than 1 table in GraphQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, schema, graphql

I am using MySQL as database and NodeJs as Backend in my application and I am integrating GraphQL in that application.

For querying with just one table works fine. When I come to join more than one table in GraphQL, it does not work.

Please guide me how to write the schema and model to join more than one table of MySQL in GraphQL.

I am using MySQL and I have 3 tables in the database.

```
User_master 
{
  id
  name,
  gender,
  status,
  email
}

Post
{
  id,
  title,
  user_id,
  post_description,
  status,
  timestamp
}

Comment_master
{
  id,
  post_id,
  user_id,
  comment,
  status,
  timestamp
}
```

How can I achieve JSON data like below by joining these 3 tables in GraphQL?

```
{
  data:{
         {
           id,
           name,
           email,
           posts:{
                   id,
                   title,
                   post_description,
                   comments:{
                              id,
                              comment,
                              timestamp
                            }
                 }
         },
         {
           id,
           name,
           email,
           posts:{
                   id,
                   title,
                   post_description,
                   comments:{
                              id,
                              comment,
                              timestamp
                            }
                 }
         }
       }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, maybe you can explain what GraphQL server implementation you are using and how you currently write your resolvers. A minimal example of what you are trying to do would be very helpful.

Comment: Hey, I have edited my question. Kindly check. Thanks